# How to add a spell check in vim for Russian language?

Tags: vim

I tried to install the Russian dictionary manually in vim, but an error occurred:

[image: [error in vim][1]]

I also tried to install dictionaries from the OpenOffice website, as they say in some manuals, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That specific FTP server seems to be currently unreachable. I will notify the mailing list but, in the meantime, you can define one of the mirrors listed at https://www.vim.org/mirrors.php as the prefered source as described under `:help spellfile.vim`.